# How to assign a pre existing panel to an array like panel[0,0]?

Tags: c#, controls

Im trying to create a chess strategy application in c#.  I have placed the panels in the form designer where they have been named panel1, panel2, ect....  I am needing to know how I can assign the panels to a 2D Array like 'chessBoardPanels[0,0]'  this would allow me to actually control the backgrounds of the panels with a command like:

```
chessBoardPanels[0,0].Background=Color.Black;
```

But it says I need a some sort of object reference.

Comment: `But it says I need a some sort of object reference.` - What does this mean?  Are you getting some sort of exception?  How is chessBoardPanels declared?

Answer (score 2):

I would rather go for something like this

```
        int numBlocks = 8;
        Panel[,] chessBoardPanels = new Panel[numBlocks, numBlocks];
        for (int iRow = 0; iRow < numBlocks; iRow++)
            for (int iColumn = 0; iColumn < numBlocks; iColumn++)
            {
                Panel p = new Panel();
                //set size
                p.Size = new Size(50, 50);
                //set back colour
                p.BackColor = (iRow + (iColumn % 2)) % 2 == 0 ? Color.Black : Color.White;
                //set location
                p.Location = new Point(50 * iRow, 50 * iColumn);
                chessBoardPanels[iRow, iColumn] = p;
                this.Controls.Add(p);
            }
```

This would allow you to create the Panels on the fly, without having to create them in the designer.

You will however have to work on a formula to handle the spacing for you.

**EDIT**

I have also added an example of how to space/set the panel blocks.

Comment: But when I try assigning the panels like this:
chessBoardPanels[2,2.BackColor=panel0;
Then later try changing the background color like:

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for creating such 2D array would be:

```
Panel[,] chessBoardPanels = new Panel[8, 8];
chessBoardPanels[0, 0] = panel1;
chessBoardPanels[0, 1] = panel2;
chessBoardPanels[0, 2] = panel3;
//...
chessBoardPanels[0, 7] = panel8;
chessBoardPanels[1, 0] = panel9;
//...
```

Comment: But it still wont allow me to change the background color like this:

Comment: @user1074119 sorry, can't see whatever you're trying to post as comment. After having such code, `chessBoardPanels[0,0].Background=Color.Black;` should work just fine.

Comment: chessBoardPanels[2,2].BackColor=Color.Red;  for some reason it doesn't change the background color   please help!!!!!

Comment: @user1074119 so please edit your question, add the exact code you're using and I'll try to see what you did wrong.

Comment: Seeing how I am having problems getting the code into this site how about if I send it to you through ur email address

Comment: @user1074119 please click "edit" below your post and add this in there,  unless you can't share your code for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

I kept a bool in my loop for the creation of my board to determine whether to use black or white as the background color. Before setting each field you must initiate the array (usually a two-dimensional one):

```
        this.Fields = new PieceButton[Board.Size, Board.Size];

        board = new Board(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < Board.Size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Board.Size; j++)
            {
                this.Fields[i, j] = new PieceButton(even ? white : black, i, j);
                this.Fields[i, j].Size = fieldSize;
                this.Fields[i, j].Location = new Point(
                    i * PieceSize + widthOffset,
                    (Board.Size - j - 1) * PieceSize + heightOffset);

                Fields[i, j].MouseDown += this.Piece_MouseDown;
                this.Controls.Add(Fields[i, j]);
                even = !even;
            }
            even = !even;
        }
```

Comment: My problem is that after assigning the panels to the array like: